# Facebook Integration and data fetching not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have used the following code to fetch data from the Facebook to my app.
I have did all the other stuff in app delegate and plist.
This sometimes works and fetched data and sometimes don't. Can anyone help me with this. I can't figure what the problem is!

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender
{
FBLoginView *loginView=[[FBLoginView alloc]init];
loginView.delegate=self;
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"first_name",
                                   @"last_name",
                                   @"location",
                                   @"id",
                                   @"access_token"];
NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", nil];

loginView.readPermissions=permissions;
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
[FBRequestConnection
 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                   id<FBGraphUser> user1,
                                   NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         firstname=user1.first_name;
         lastname=user1.last_name;
         city=[user1.location objectForKey:@"name"];
         email=user1[@"email"];
         fbid=user1.id;
         Loggedin=@"Y";
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:Loggedin forKey:@"token"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
     }
     if (![fbid isEqualToString:@""])
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Facebooksegue" sender: self];
}
     NSLog(@"%@",firstname);
NSLog(@"%@",lastname);
NSLog(@"%@",city);
NSLog(@"%@",email);
NSLog(@"%@",fbid);

 }];

}
```

My AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[FBSession class];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have used the Facebook SDK...If i need to provide more information please comment and i will respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation and I had used almost the same code as you did.
My problem was with the test Facebook id which I had used. I hadn't had it verified so it didn't respond with the email. Try using another account and it might work. If not check whether your app is authorized with the Facebook account synchronized with your account in the settings.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the blue project icon at the top left, select your target, go to build settings, find other linker flags, add -ObjC.  This will make it so that the entire framework gets statically linked and thus you can reference FBLoginView in the storyboard successfully.

[image: Example of how it should look]

Comment: In the other linker flag i see debug and release.
Where exactly should i add -ObjC?

Comment: Just add a space after debug and release and add -ObjC afterward.

Comment: I added an example above of how it looks in one of my projects.